# ExtJS redirectTo without save url in history

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

Suppose I have the following code:

```
...
routes: {
    'someurl:{param}': {
        action: 'action',
        before: 'beforeaction'
    }
},

...

beforeaction: function(param, action) {
    if (!param) {
        action.stop();
        this.redirecTo('someurl:defaultparam');
    }
    action.resume();
}
...
```

So, when I open `host/someurl`, application redirects me to `host/someurl:defaultparam`. This part works well.
But I can't return to url before `host/someurl` by using 'Back' browser button, because when I returning to host/someurl application redirects me to `host/someurl:defaultparam` again. I tried changing `redirectTo` to

```
history.replaceState(..., host/#someurl:defaultparam);
history.go(0);
```

But each redirection reloads the page.

So, how to use ExtJs redirectTo and replace url in history?

**Update:** I replaced `history.go(0);` on `this.redirectTo('someurl:defaultparam', true);`. Now I have promblem when redirecting to some url two or more times in a row

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [API docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.app.BaseController-method-redirectTo) and the [actual code](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/source/BaseController.html#Ext-app-BaseController-method-redirectTo), it looks like `redirectTo()` manages `Ext.util.History` -- which is just a layer on top of `window.location.hash`. Unfortunately, since the back button is tightly-coupled with `window.location` there isn't a clean way to accomplish what you need.

I have in the past been able to override [Ext.app.router.Router.recognize()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.app.route.Router-method-recognize) -- which intercepts all Ext JS routes, and might enable you to change the URL/hash before much happens. I'm not entirely sure if it helps your specific case, though.

Comment: Thanks! I missed, that method redirectTo has second argument (force). I just replaced history.go(0) on this.redirectTo(url, true).